Creating Collidable Dynamic Toruses with Holes Using concavePolyhedron
I'm working on a SceneKit project where I need to create dynamic toruses with holes that can collide with each other. I've tried setting up the physics bodies for these toruses using both convexHull and concavePolyhedron shapes. While I can successfully create the toruses with holes using concavePolyhedron, I'm facing an issue where these toruses do not collide with each other.
Here's a brief overview of what I've implemented:
// Creating the torus geometry
let torus = SCNTorus(ringRadius: 1.0, pipeRadius: 0.3)
torus.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue

// Setting up the physics body
let shapeOptions = [SCNPhysicsShape.Option.type: SCNPhysicsShape.ShapeType.concavePolyhedron]
let physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: torusNode, options: shapeOptions)
let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: physicsShape)
torusNode.physicsBody = physicsBody

// Scene setup
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(torusNode)

Even though I've set the physics body type to dynamic and used concavePolyhedron, the toruses pass through each other without any collision. I need the toruses to be dynamic and collidable, ideally with accurate collision detection considering their hollow shapes.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or can suggest a way to get accurate collision detection for dynamic toruses in SceneKit?

My observations for the SCNTorus were, that when creating a default dynamic body, the hole in the middle is kind of ignored. So, if you do not throw things trough that hole, you can use the default dynamic Body. When Working with the concavePolyhedron, the dynamic Physics no longer applies. Dynamic Bodies cannot be of type concavePolihedron. So, if you do not need that hole in the middle. Go for default. When you want a Torus to be dynamic with hole, I consider you to model one in Blender or similar and import it to your scene. Then set the default dynamic Body. (I never tested a Torus).

@ZAY how does designing in Blender and importing a model change the behaviour? Most physics engines use convex hull for creating a physics body shape from the original

I really often noticed differences in behavoiur of Geometry Objects created with external programs, compared to the generated build-in SceneKit geometries, especially when it comes to physics. Give it a try
